# How to override default "text" cursor on mousedown, mousemove?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't get cursor to be `e-resize` when `mousedown` and `mousemove` events are happening.
I did somehow manage to do that, but then it didn't work anymore and I forgot how I got it to work.

Here is example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/cuVJd/) , when you drag handle bar it cursor does not change to `e-resize` as it should.

I'm thinking there is some kind of incorrect `cursor: e-resize` assignment.

Here is current css:

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.splitter {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.splitter.vertical .leftPane {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-right: 5px;
    right: 25%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.splitter.vertical .rightPane {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
    left: auto;
    width: 25%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.splitter.vertical .handleBar {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: green;
    right: 25%;
    width: 5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: e-resize;
}
.splitter.active .handleClone {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: green;
    width: 5px;
    cursor: e-resize;
    z-index: 3;
}
.splitter .content-overlay {
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
}
.splitter.active .content-overlay {
    display: block;
}
.splitter.active {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: e-resize;
}
.splitter.hide-right .handleBar {
    display: none !important;
}
.splitter.hide-right .rightPane {
    display: none !important;
}
.splitter.hide-right .leftPane {
    right: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: it is working in my browser !

Comment: @FaceOfJock If the read the question carefully, you can identify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Chrome thinks that you want to select any text that might be present so it changes the cursor as though you are highlighting text. When selection starts, you can prevent the default action, which includes changing the cursor.

I added this line:

```
container[0].onselectstart = function(e){e.preventDefault();return false;}
```

Move it where you would like but it works.

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuVJd/2/)

Found on the [jQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/chrome-text-select-cursor-on-drag)

**Edit:**

I would move that line into the container.on('mousemove') for clarity

```
container.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    var rightPos = container.width() - (e.pageX - container.offset().left);

    this.onselectstart = function(e){e.preventDefault();return false;}

    handleClone.css({
        right: rightPos - 2
    });
})
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but perhaps a `-webkit-user-select: none` will work?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I'm not the biggest fan of having to use javascript for something that is a style issue, but I have not found a better solution. If there is one, I would love to know about it.

Comment: Thanks. Thou I don't like to use extra javascript, I coudln't seem to find a better solution.

Comment: Ha, yep. I defer to my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using javascript to solve the problem? Do the event handlers `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` on the element and make them run a function like this one:

```
    function mousecursor() { 
    document.getElementById("mygreatid").style.cursor = "eResize"; 
    }
```

Hope that helps :)